# How can I check if a given directory is accessible?

Tags: bash, directory, file-permissions, exit-code

I am currently writing a script that will list all specific files in a directory. What I need the script to do is to verify that the directory is accessible. I am currently using this bit of code:

```
# variable used to get the file permissions of the given  directory 
perm=$(stat -c %a "$dir_name")

if [ "$perm" != "755" -o "$perm" != "777" ]; then
  echo ERROR: "Directory $dir_name cannot be accessed check permissions"
  echo USAGE: "ass2 <directory>"
  exit 3
fi
```

This will work for checking if they have those specific octal permissions, but I was wondering if there is any other way to check if the directory is accessible or not, and to return an error if it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use Bash Conditional Expressions

On Unix and Linux, practically everything is a file...including directories! If you don't care about execute or write permissions, you can simply check whether a directory is readable with the `-r` test. For example:

```
# Check if a directory is readable.
mkdir -m 000 /tmp/foo
[[ -r /tmp/foo ]]; echo $?
1
```

You can also check whether a file is a traversable directory in a similar way. For example:

```
# Check if variable is a directory with read and execute bits set.
dir_name=/tmp/bar
mkdir -m 555 "$dir_name"
if [[ -d "$dir_name" ]] && [[ -r "$dir_name" ]] && [[ -x "$dir_name" ]]; then
    : # do something with the directory
fi
```

You can make the conditionals as simple or as complex as you like, but you don't have to compare octals or parse *stat* just to check permissions. Bash conditionals can do the job directly.