# How to check a directory has a read/write permission

Tags: shell, unix, permissions, directory

I have a directory as shown

```
d-wx--x--x 2 bcheudev bcheudev  4096 Jun 18 06:16 test
```

which shows the directory does not have read permission.

But when i check the same through shell script it's giving result as dir test has read permission.

```
export IN_DIR=$MMHOME/test   
if [ -d ${IN_DIR}  ]    
then    
   if [ ! -r ${IN_DIR} ]    
   then    
      echo "${IN_DIR} Directory is not readable.">>$log_name    
      exit 255   
   fi    
else    
   echo "${IN_DIR} Directory does not Exists.">>$log_name
   exit 255    
fi
```

inside second if it's not going.

Please help

Comment: Your script works well on my machine. Something else happens on yours... Make a clean experiment...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a given directory is accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349042/how-can-i-check-if-a-given-directory-is-accessible)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `root` will always have read permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your condition is incorrect.
Try with :

```
if ! [[ -r ${IN_DIR} ]]
  then
    echo "${IN_DIR} Directory is not readable.">>$log_name
    exit 255
fi
```