# how do I check if the directory "d" exists but does not have the right to read for the current user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a hand for a program in bash.
How can I check if the "d" directory exists but does not have the right to read for the current user?

```
if [ -d $d ]; #Check if directory exist
then
    #check the permission
fi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a given directory is accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27349042/608639), [How to check a directory has a read/write permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30930434/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ mkdir d
$ sudo sh -c 'chown root:root d && chmod 700 d'

$ [[ -d d && ! -r d ]] && echo "d exists but is not readable"
d exists but is not readable
```

If you want portable shell syntax: `[ -d d ] && ! [ -r d ]`

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions